# how to send a mail from plone site

Tags: python-2.7, plone

Can anyone tell me how to send a mail from plone site. What i m trying to do is(will list out my points)

1. i have a template page(html page) called contact us.In which the user can enter his/her name, email id, address, etc. After entering the things he have to submit it to a particular mail id.
2. I create a .py file for getting those values from contact us html page.
3. After getting the values, it should be mailed to a particular mail id.

my html page somewhat looks like like:

```
<html>
<form action="mailto" method = "post" name="mailto">
   Name :<input type="text" name="fname" />
   address :<input type="text" name="address"/>
</form>
</html>
```

**mailto.py**

```
class MailTo(BrowserView)
  def __init__(self,context,request):
     self.context = context
     self.request = request 

  def registerdetail(self):
      mailhost = self.context.MailHost
      form= self.request.form
      name=form.get('fname')
      address=form.get('address')

      mto = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
      msg="""
          Name:%s
          Address:%s
          """ %(name,address)

      mailhost.send(messageText=msg, mto=mto, mfrom='yyy@yahoo.com')

      return self.sucesspage()
```

I tested it  directly by giving my own mailid in "mto=gsgfsf@gmail.com" but i didnit receive any mail. can anyone tell whats wrong with my things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That should work if you have a mail server setup and configured in plone. Check your mail log file and see what's going on there.

Comment: @@vangheem : I checked my @@mail-controlpanel.. Everything is fine but still i cant able to send mail.

Comment: I tested  mail configuration in @@mail-controlpanel by sending a test mail. in terminal i can see the output like                    "Hi,

This is a test message sent from the Plone 'Mail settings' control panel. Y=
our receipt of this message (at the address specified in the Site 'From' ad=
dress field) indicates that your e-mail server is working!

Have a nice day.

Love,

Plone
"but no mail received in my inbox...

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer as "correct" :-)

Comment: Did you forgot to remove PrintingMailHost from your installed products? We just had someone on the mailing list that did the exact same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You'll find it much easier to simply use PloneFormGen (a popular add-on for Plone) to build your form. You can make the email destination for the form configurable by following the instructions at: http://developer.plone.org/reference_manuals/active/ploneformgen/select_mail.html

Answer (score 3):

According to what you say on the mailing lists, your problem is that you installed the developer tool [Products.PrintingMailHost](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.PrintingMailHost).

With that installed emails are printed to the console instead of being sent. This is so you can test sending emails without actually having to send emails.

Comment: +1 for the patience to collect infos from crossposts and making the rigth conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Verify you have configured Plone to send mail first. In `Site Setup -> Mail`, enter your mail server  information and click *Save and Send test e-mail*.

[image]

Then using `MailHost` in Python should work (unless you are using Products.PrintingMailHost which prints email instead of sending it.)

Comment: @@aclark : I configured mailhost using some documentations from net and the way you told. Still i didnt receive any mail

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir: What happens, if you click on 'Save and send test e-mail', visible in the sreenshort Alex kindly took the effort to provide for you? And again: *Please* avoid cross-postings.

Comment: @Ida: when i click 'Save and send test e-mail' i got this ms at the top of the page 
"Info
    Success! Check your mailbox for the test message."                                                             i checked my mail id then but no mail received

Comment: @NirmalaSudhir: Well that's good on terms, that you managed finally to verify, that your SMTP-server-settings are correct. So the problem must be in your code. At a glance, I remember troubles, if the site-from-address differs from the `mfrom` address and that this can also depend on the politics of your third-party email provider. Try using the same address for `mfrom` as you have in the 'Site from'-address.

Comment: @IdaEbkes: I checked my code also . I see that from address in plone site '@@mail-controlpanel' and mfrom mail id is same.